# How to set subtitle/subtext for FCM push notifications?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is what I mean by subtitle/subtext, the text that says "This is a subtitle" beside the app name:
[image]

I can't figure out how to do this with FCM. According to this link: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) I can set "subtitle" but that is only for iOS. Is this possible to set this for Android with FCM? Because my screenshot shows it's possible for android apps to show a subtitle/subtext next to the app name for push notifications and I know WhatsApp does this so I'd assume it's possible. Thanks

Comment: FCM subtitle works only for ios.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is the `summaryText` key. I have not tried this and by the looks the OS decides when this should be displayed. I cannot say this will be displayed for all messages or only grouped ones.

```
{
    "notification": {
       "title": "This is a title",
       "body": "Sample message",
       "summaryText": "This is a subtitle"
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean the text beside the app name in the push notification. In my screenshot it's the text "This is a subtitle"

Comment: I had a hunt around and found very little information about it. Came across this video which although is not flutter but native android uses the setSummaryText.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZC4x4eEBU9U&t=8m50s. See that he has the email set in this location

Comment: Thanks for your help, seems like it's not possible in FCM